Android Compose navigationBarsPadding() doesn't work on first launch
I'm using in my app the method navigationBarsPadding() to add a bottom padding, with the same value as the navigation bars, to a composable. Unfortunately, this doesn't work when I launch the app until I rotate the screen.
Indeed, as shown in the screenshots below the button at the bottom right is partially hide by the navigation bar on first launch, and everything appears as desired when I rotate the screen.
Is anyone else encounter the same behavior with Compose? Please how can I solve this?
First launch

After screen rotation

This is the code within the onCreate() method of the main Activity:
MainTheme() {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
          .fillMaxSize()
          .navigationBarsPadding()
          .background(Color.Transparent)
          .border(
              width = 0.dp,
              color = Color.Transparent,
              shape = RectangleShape
           ),
          shape = RectangleShape,
          color = Color.Transparent,
          contentColor = contentColorFor(Color.Transparent),
          tonalElevation = 0.dp,
          shadowElevation = 0.dp,
          border = null,
   ) {

    ....

    }
}

Device used:
Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android 12
Settings:
Android Studio --> Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 RC
SDK Build-Tools --> 34.0.0
AGP --> 8.4.0-rc02
Kotlin --> 1.9.23
Compose --> BOM 2024.04.00 | Compiler 1.5.11
Dagger --> 2.51.1
Min SDK --> 26
Compile SDK --> 34
Target SDK --> 34

I found the solution!
In onCreate(), I'm using the Android enableEdgeToEdge() function to enable the edge to edge display for my ComponentActivity.
Previously, this function was added before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState). After moving this after the super.onCreate(savedInstanceState), everything works fine now.
Before
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

Now
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
}

